# How to change the Navigation Drawer Icon?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation

I want to change my navigation drawer icon. But after I changed the icon, the app crashes. The error code shows something with boolean, which I sadly don't understand. I can't find my failure. Did I implement it in a wrong way?
Sorry, but I'm new on Android Studio and this question could be maybe a little bit unnecessary. But tried a lot to solve the problem. However, I couldn't find a solution yet.

That is the MainClass. I generated a variable outside the OnCreate-method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ExpandableListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expandableList;
    List<ExpandedMenuModel> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<ExpandedMenuModel, List<String>> listDataChild;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    Drawable drawable;

    WebView webView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_view);

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

        drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),   R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, getTheme());

        mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
        mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });

        ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
```

For more check this [link](https://mobikul.com/change-hamburger-icon-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned value to:

```
mDrawerToggle
```

before calling `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled` on it here:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Didn't I do it outside the method?

Comment: No, see here: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html how to implement it